# How to start a daemon with gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, freeze

I have seen a few examples of querying the daemons PID via `ps aux` and then attaching it to gdb.

However, i have a robot which is running a program written by me, while at certain points, the program is freezing. I have exhausted my attempts to debug it normally.

SO I need to attach a gdb instance with it - while the robot is away. I dont have the option to use LTE and then reverse ssh whlie it runs, it doesn't have a wireless. For ethernet - it is going up to a couple of kilometer from where I stand. So I need to :

1. launch my process with program as a daemon, this is a requirement  (i.e. when the robot reboots, the program starts)
2. attach a GDB instance to it, without having access to the robot (no screen, keyboard... etc)
3. Log all the output of GDB

with this in mind, I have tried, in the daemon file myservice.service:

```
ExecStart="gdb --exec=/path/to/file /path/to/inputfile.txt --eval-command=run" &
```

this doesn't work. the result is (after `systemctl status myservice`, we see:)

```
myservice.service - my service
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
Active: inactive (dead
```

SO, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

PS: My service is written of C++, uses heavy serial communication, uses the DJI OSDK to communicate with A3 flight controller, and runs on a raspberry pi zero.

Comment: How about simply launching a gdb session for your program at system startup? I don't understand why it specifically has to be run as a daemon.

Comment: because that is the requirement of the final user.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you run it as a daemon while you debug it? Seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: the problem is not appearing when you do not run this as a daemon